# Android: ListView that flows in the background of a overlayed TextField

Tags: android, listview

I would like to have a ListView, that flows in the background of a defined TextView while scrolling upwards (right handed view on picture). On the left handed view (status quo), I used a relative Layout, but the used elements within it are fix. So it looks very choppy while scrolling.

Preferable I would like to implement such a functionality in my list.xml, if this is possible?

Link to picture for better understanding of my idea:

[image]

My activity.xml looks like:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/hintergrund1"
    tools:context="com.example.apptest2.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

   <EditText
      android:id="@+id/text1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
      android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" >

  </ListView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Interesting topic, I'd like to do the following and therefor interested in a answer as well :-)

Comment: Me  too...eagerly waiting for an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dunno if i understand correctly but try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/hintergrund1"
    tools:context="com.example.apptest2.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" >

  </ListView>

   <EditText
      android:id="@+id/text1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No, this wont satisfy my Idea :(

Comment: What Sc0re wants is to have initially the list below TextField and as the user drags the list, it will animate below the TextField and remain there.

Comment: Exactly gunar, u got a vote for that explanation. I feel like my description wasn't clear enough.